# Add futur regressor to prediction with Neural Prophet

Tags: python, neural-network, prediction

I would like to use futur regressors in order to predict temperature in a room with NeuralProphet. Ive followed the documentation and done :

```
d = {'ds':new_ts,'y':new_value,'A':x}

d1={'A':my_series_predict.values}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ds"])

#Instanciation de l'algorithme
m=NeuralProphet(n_forecasts=forecast,n_lags=lags,daily_seasonality=True,weekly_seasonality=False,yearly_seasonality=True)

m = m.add_future_regressor(name='A')
future_regressors_df =pd.DataFrame(d1)
metrics = m.fit(df)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(df=df)
forecast = m.predict(df=future,decompose=False)
```

With A, my regressor. D is the dataframe of past values (temperature and regressor). D1 are the values of my regressor in the future.

I got this error : "ValueError: Future values of all user specified regressors not provided"

I can understand this because we do not use "future_regressors_df" at all. But the documentation don't use anything else.

How can I specify to my model the futur regressor values ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add future regressor we can't use "make_future_dataframe" because values of future regressor are not put in the future dataframe.

We must build our own future dataframe and specify the future values like that :

```
#Past values dataframe
d = {'ds':new_ts,'y':new_value,'A':my_series.values}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ds"])

m=NeuralProphet(n_forecasts=forecast,n_lags=lags,daily_seasonality=True,weekly_seasonality=False,yearly_seasonality=True)

m = m.add_future_regressor(name='A')
metrics = m.fit(df)

#Dataframe of future ds and regressors values
fu={"ds":my_series_predict.index,"y":None,"A":my_series_predict.values}
fut=pd.DataFrame(fu)
future=pd.concat([df,fut])

#Make the forecast
forecast = m.predict(df=future,decompose=False)
```